# How To Read and print text file data once in My Code Keeps On printing it JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

hi i am new to jsp i ahve written code that prints data from text file but it keeps on printing it my code is,

files that i imported are,

```
 <%@page language="java" import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
    <%@page language="java" import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@page language="java" import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>

 try
                               {
            String strpath="/var/test.log";
              ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

  FileReader fr = new FileReader(strpath);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  String currentRecord;
  while((currentRecord = br.readLine()) != null)
rows.add(currentRecord);
  br.close();
  while (rows!=null)
           {
            out.println(rows);
                       }



                               }

        catch(IOException e){

        out.print(e.getMessage());

        }
```

while i have text file location mention in the code and it contains text in this format,

```
[Red] apple is red
[Orange] orange is orange
[yellow]mango is yellow
```

my code keep on printing it how to fix it ?

if i want to use "rows.add(currentRecord.split("["));"

inorder to print data as similar as in the file then how it would be i used it but it gave errors.. .

Hopes for your suggestions .. .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Object row: rows)
{
  out.println(row);
}
```

Comment: @syed what's the output you get when you use this?

Comment: type miss match can not convert from element typr object to string :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `<c:import/>` You should try `JSTL` instead of writing Java code in JSP.

```
<c:import url="file.log" var="data"/>
<pre>
   <c:out value="${data}"/>
</pre>
```